# Add zeros (if necessary) to a number in access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a table that contains employee numbers. They need to be 5 numbers long (#####). However, sometimes the data entry doesn't quite make that happen, and there are only 4 or 3. How can I ensure that all numbers are 5 digits long?

EDIT:  Sorry, forgot to mention, data entry takes place through a bank, in a different country. I have absolutely no control over how the data is presented, I only have to deal with it once it is downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check at data entry time with either an [input mask](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/control-data-entry-formats-with-input-masks-HA010096452.aspx) or an event:

```
EmpNo= Right("00000" & EmpNo,5)
```

Or

```
EmpNo = Format([EmpNo],"00000")
```

If the data is already entered, you can do something similar with a query. This requires that the field is text.

```
UPDATE Table SET EmpNo = Format([EmpNo],"00000")
```

Select

```
SELECT Format(EmpNo,"00000") FROM table
```

Comment: Thanks Remou, I edited my question. As I say up there, I have no way to control data entry. How could left pad the number to ensure it is always 5 digits (from my query)?

Comment: You can use format without updating, but this will not be of much use if you need to join. Otherwise, you can update, as illustrated above. It all depends on what you want to do next.